# RedHat Basics - Where do I put my files?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a box that's running Red Hat 4.8.1-1. First, where besides my personal users directory does one store 'production' files? `/data`? `/`? `/where_ever_I_want`?

Answer (score 2):

There are some generally-adhered-to stardards for linux filesystems:

[Here is a generic Linux fs overview](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html)

[Here is the RedHat-specific Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html)

Based on these, creating an `/opt/production/` would be a good possibility.

However, many organizations roll their own so yes, you could create a `/data` without issue.

The main consideration is [if the system is partitioned](http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-partition.html) over several disk partitions, you want to create your directory in a partition that will be available and have the desired space. Because of this `/home/shared` is sometimes used (or in your case `/home/proddata` would be just as good).

In the case that your data has to be accessed on the web or something else specific, refer to the application recommendations. (e.g. apache html files in `/var/www/httpd/`).